# Plot a graph of sum of sales values by location

Tags: r

I have a *dataset* with location and sales per date. How do I sum the values only by location and graphically represent the same:

```
location date           sales
a          11/2/2015      100 
b          11/3/2015      10
c           ..            500
a                         20
a                         10
```

graph should look like:

> a -->130 b-->10 c-->500

Answer (score 0):

Using the `plyr` library:

```
library(plyr)
result <- ddply(df, .(location), summarise, sum = sum(sales))
> result
  location sum
1        a 130
2        b  10
3        c 500
```

And you can get a rudimentary plot by simply calling:

```
plot(result$location, result$sum)
```

**Data:**

```
df <- data.frame(location=c("a", "b", "c", "a", "a"),
                 date=c("11/2/2015", "11/3/2015", "11/4/2015", "11/5/2015", "11/6/2015"),
                 sales=c(100, 10, 500, 20, 10))
```